# MP test size $\alpha$ for testing $H_0:f(x)=N(0,1) \text{ vs. } H_A:f(x)=Cauchy(0,1)$

Tags: hypothesis-testing, inference

**Question:** Let $X$ be a single observation from a pdf $f(x)$. Find a Most Powerful test size $\alpha$ for testing $H_0:f(x)=N(0,1) \text{ vs } H_A:f(x)=Cauchy(0,1)$

$\ $

**Attempt:** According to the Neyman-Pearson lemma, any MP level $\alpha$ test will reject $H_0$ for large values of the likelihood ratio, which is $$\Lambda(x) = \frac{\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{1}{1 + x^2}}{\frac{1}{\root \of{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}} = c \frac{e^{x^2/2}}{1 + x^2} = c \frac{e^z}{1 + 2z}$$ writing $z = \frac{x^2}{2}$. We want to know for which values of $z$, $\frac{e^z}{1 + 2z}$ is larger than a threshold $k$.

Now there is a hint that was given which states:

> A plot of the function $\frac{e^z}{1 + 2z}$ shows that depending on the value of $k$, the set of values of $z$ for which $\frac{e^z}{1 + 2z} > k$ is either an one sided interval of the form $z > b$ or a union of two disjoint intervals $z < a, z > b$. It is a union of two disjoint intervals if the threshold $k <1$

[image: graph of f(z) vs z, z>0]

I did this graph on desmos to check it myself. I would have preferred it if I could have found the subject matter of the hint mathematically, as opposed to graphically looking at it.

Nonetheless, using the hint, the rejection regions of the MP test can take one of two different forms:$|X|> C$,or $|X|< A \bigcup |X|> B$

$\ $

**My question is:**

1. From here, what is the MP test size $\alpha$ that completes the solution more explicity?
2. Could someone please denote the rejection region(s) graphically for better understanding?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Have you tried making a plot of $\frac{\exp(z)}{1+2z}$? What does that look like?

Comment: Both distributions are symmetrical about $0.$ What would a one-sided test look like? Under $H_0,$ your single observation is equally likely to be positive or negative.

Comment: You might want to add the [`self-study`](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) tag to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about rejecting $H_0$ if $|X|> 1.96?$
Then $\alpha = P(\mathrm{Rej}\,H_0|H_0\,\mathrm{true})= 0.05 = 5\%.$

```
2*pnorm(-1.96)
[1] 0.04999579
```

Also, $\beta = P(\mathrm{Not\,Rej}\,H_0|H_0\,\mathrm{false})=0.70.$

```
diff(pt(c(-1.96,1.96),1))
[1] 0.6996571
```

So the power of the single-observation test is about $30\%.$

In the figure below, the rejection region is outside the
vertical black lines in both tails.

```
hdr = "Densities of Std Norm (solid blue) and Cauchy"
curve(dnorm(x), -6,6, col="blue", lwd=2, ylab="PDF", main=hdr)
 curve(dt(x,1), add=T, col="maroon", lwd=2, lty="dotted")
 abline(h=0, col="green2"); abline(v=c(-1.96, 1.96))
```

[image]

Because the mean of $n=4$ observations from a standard normal
distribution has $\bar X \sim \mathsf{Norm}(\mu=0, \sigma=1/2)$
and the mean of $n$ observations from the Cauchy distribution
is again (the original) Cauchy. One can find that the critical
values $\pm c=0.980$ give $\alpha=0.05$ and $\beta = 0.494.$

```
q=qnorm(.025, 0, 1/2);  q
[1] -0.979982
diff(pt(c(q,-q),1))
[1] 0.4935639

hdr = "Densities of NORM(0,.5) (solid blue) and Std. Cauchy"
curve(dnorm(x,0,.5), -6,6, col="blue", lwd=2, ylab="PDF", main=hdr)
 curve(dt(x,1), add=T, col="maroon", lwd=2, lty="dotted")
 abline(h=0, col="green2"); abline(v=c(-.98, .98))
```

[image]

Comment: The fact that I'm plotting  a function of $z$, where $z = \frac{x^2}{2}$ which means that $z$ is always positive, which in turn ensures that $\frac{exp(z)}{1+2z}$ is always positive, is confusing me.  Could a graph of rejection region be given? Thanks!

Comment: Just added figure.

Comment: Recently added figure. // Just look at it logically: $\Lambda$ is big in the tails where std Cauchy density > std Norm density. If we're to have $\alpha = 0.05$ then we know "tails" means beyond $\pm 1.96$ in the two tails. Signif level is governed by $H_0.$ // Pick $a = -1.96, b = 1.96$ and you're done.

Comment: Have you considered that maybe is was a mistake to convert from $x^2/2,$ where $x$ can be positive or negative, to $z,$ where this is obscured. // Once again, can you explain how a 'one-sided' test would arise? Can you write the null and alternative hypotheses for that?

Comment: You're right! converting to z was the mistake in the hint itself. I plotted the graph for f(x) vs x, and its clear that one-sided interval doesn't make sense. For all k>1, it will always be a disjoint union of the form $X<-|A| \bigcup X>|A|$ for some $A \in \Bbb R$ which depends on k. Thanks!

Comment: Glad you resolved everything. // Often in tests based on a likelihood ratio it's not easy to sort out the exact critical value from the LR itself. Strategy that sometimes helps: Depend on the LR to tell you the direction(s) for Reject. Rely on knowledge of the null distribution to get the exact critical value, Then reconcile everything.

Comment: I have a question. In the very first equation, I used the inverse of the likelihood ratio test than what is used in the Neyman-Pearson. According to theroem, its supposed to me $\frac{\text{Normal}}{\text{Cauchy}}$, while I calculated for $\frac{\text{Cauchy}}{\text{Normal}}$. How does this affect mine and your overall answer and graph? I have plotted for both, and the new one is in red while old one is in blue here:- https://www.desmos.com/calculator/1qdscxnich

Comment: It doesn't matter as long as, in the end, you reject normal in the normal tails where Cauchy likelihood is relatively high. But if this is for hwk, then you should work the problem according to the statement of the theorem in your text or class notes.